# What is the right way to reply to an email with Mailgun?

Tags: email, mailgun

The following use case seems pretty common to me when using Mailgun:

- A program is getting an email (for example via the Message API).
- The program is processing the message, whatever that means here.
- The program is replying to the sender by sending an email via the Message API. Think: "We've just processed your message!"

This last API call is expected to act as the regular "Reply to" feature of any mail client:

- `To` is the original message `From`. Also, take `Reply-to` into account, if any.
- `From` is the original message `To`
- Subject should be prefixed with `Re:` (or something else, depending on the locale)
- `Message-Id` must be set accordingly
- ...

This does not sound like rocket science, but there are a lot of nitty-gritty to handle to get this done correctly.

I was expecting a dedicated entry point in Mailgun Message API for this. Like: specify the original message Id and tell if this is a "reply" or "reply all" and Mailgun does the rest.

Two questions in one:

- Is there a way to do this natively in Mailgun? An API entry point I missed, maybe ?
- Else, is there a documented procedure to do this properly?

Comment: There is no such API entry point. Source: MailGun support.

Comment: How did you end up doing it? Did you just use the rules that you wrote above and it worked fine?

Comment: @theadriangreen Exactly!

Comment: @philippe_b did you also set `In-Reply-To` header with the message-id that you were replying to? Could you let us know the headers that need setting?

Comment: @GautamKumarSamal After all these years, I must admit I forgot about this issue :-/